# Selenium, python, Xpath on youtube, why does it not find the element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am creating automation tests for a video in YouTube.

```
def testComment(self):

    time.sleep(2)
    #find comment line
    self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="placeholder-area"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #If you have to log, pass
    if self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="identifierId"]').is_displayed():
        pass
```

Ignore sleep, I added it to be sure the page was loaded, but still nothing. What am I doing wrong?
The rest of the tests are not failing.

[the screenshot of the page and xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC29I.png)

The error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="placeholder-area"]"}

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: Yes:    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="placeholder-area"]"}

Comment: @Najgorzata what are you trying to do there, exactly? - also, add the video_id in the question. I think it's the one - `zO6D_BAuYCI` -, right?

Comment: Hi Marco, I was trying to test if you can comment without active account. If you click on the comment area you get login page

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, it turns out I have to scroll to see the area. Hard scroll like:

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")

You wre great help, I would not think the comments are not loaded without scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because the comments haven't been loaded yet after 2 seconds. You can try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def testComment(self):
    #find comment line
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="placeholder-area"]'))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #If you have to log, pass
    if self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="identifierId"]').is_displayed():
        pass
```

PS: If window width is too small, YouTube comments won't load at all.

Comment: It is "Crazy Little Thing Called Love" official video. So it is not taken down...

Comment: Beats me then, as your code works on my end. Can you try increasing the 1st sleep to 5 seconds or something, to make sure the page loads properly? Comments can load after video.

Comment: I was waiting even 20 secs, I have no idea why it does not work. Maybe I should scroll?